# How to find tha't circular list's begin?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, iterator

I'm trying to implement about list and iterator of list like C++ STL.

The node in list is defined like this:

```
struct Node{
  Node *prev,*next;
  value_type data;
};
```

And I want to overloading operator > and < :

```
bool list_iterator::operator>(const iterator_impl_base &rhs) const
bool list_iterator::operator<(const iterator_impl_base &rhs) const
```

which means if I need to call next to reach rhs.node , it will return 0 in > and return 1 in <.

if I need to call prev to reach rhs.node , it return 1 in > and return 0 in <.

And I implement list using circular list. Below is one part of list class :

```
class List : public ordered_container {
 protected:
  Node* begin_;
  Node* end_;
  size_type size_;
 public:
    List::List() : end_(new Node){
        begin_ = end_->prev = end_->next = end_;
        size_=0;
    }
}
```

So , I don't know how to distinguish whether I just pass the begin_ of list. Can someone help me about that? Thankyou.

Comment: What's the context of the question? If you just need a circular buffer, would a vector suffice while applying mod when indexing, to the length of the vector? Or could you just use [`boost::circular_buffer`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html)?

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn I want to know how to overloading those 2 operator. What I need to do is to implement myself list and iterator which works like the list in STL. Moreover I can't use anything in STL.

Comment: @willy: And did you actually mean [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) or [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)? I'm asking since an ordering relation doesn't make sense on a circular buffer. Every element is before every other element, it's a circle...

Comment: boost is not in the STL. Tell your teacher you found a nice loophole and use `boost::circular_buffer`

Comment: @phlipsy for example, I have a list : 1->2->3->4 , and 4->1 since it's circule , and 1 is begin_ , 4 is end_.  In this situation , 1<2<3<4. When consider which is bigger or which is smaller will not care it's circular , just see which node use prev will get begin_ faster.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn Then I'll get 0 :((

Comment: It's not common to implement `<` for list iterators, usually you only need `==` and `!=`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, using `operator<` to mean "precedes" is *weird*. I know it's an exercise, I just don't want you thinking this is normal.

Now, your circular list stores the begin and end in the top-level container object, so there's no way for a node itself to tell whether it's the head, or the trail, or whether a reversal wraps around. Only the container can tell this.

The usual solution for circular lists is to have a sentinel node between head and tail. Then `sentinel.next` is the head, `sentinel.prev` is the tail, and you need some way to mark the sentinel itself (either a magic value of `data` or an extra flag). This sentinel node can then replace the two pointers in your container object (so you're not wasting any space).

When you traverse the list, it's still circular, but you can tell if you pass the sentinel that you've wrapped around.

The sentinel has the additional benefit that you never have to worry about nullptrs in an empty list.

---

Incidentally, I find it very strange that instructors keep using doubly-linked lists and *don't* show the sentinel arrangement. It's described within a couple of pages in a copy of Elson's Data Structures book I've inherited, and that was published in 1975. What's the point of deliberately teaching a *bad* doubly-linked list?

If they wanted you to figure this out for yourself, they ought to have you working through the fundamental list operations rather than these odd precedes/succeeds operators, as the basic operations can actually work without a sentinel but are visibly improved with its addition.

Answer (score 0):

An element `a` is less than another element `b` iff you can reach `b` before `end` by following `next`.

An element `a` is greater than another element `b` iff `b` is less than `a`.